# $\mathbb{Q}$-Linear Combinations of Floor Functions taking values in $\{0,1\}$

Tags: number-theory

The linear combinations $\lfloor x \rfloor - 2 \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor \tfrac{x}{2} \rfloor - \lfloor \tfrac{x}{3} \rfloor - \lfloor \tfrac{x}{5} \rfloor + \lfloor \tfrac{x}{30} \rfloor$ can be shown to take values only in $\{ 0, 1 \}$, where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

I'd like to compute arbitrarily long linear combinations of this type, namely, $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_k \lfloor b_k x \rfloor$, where $a_k, b_k \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$. It is necessary but not sufficient that the sequence $\{a_k, b_k \}$ satisfy the condition $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_{k} b_k = 0$. Perhaps I'm missing something simple, but I don't quite see a general method of generating such functions beyond a brute force (and time consuming) search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the introduction to his paper correctly, the classification of such linear combinations has been completed by [Bober](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1977) following earlier work of Vasyunin. The arbitrary long linear combinations you ask for don't exist

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed one of several *necessary* conditions that $\sum a_k b_k=0$.

**Lemma** Assume that $f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\left\lfloor b_k x\right\rfloor$ with $a_k, b_k\in\mathbb Q^\times$ has the property that $f(x)\in\{0,1\}$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.
Then $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_k = 0\qquad \mathrm{and}\qquad\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\in\{0, -1, -2\}.$$
If the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is not constant, then 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k= -1.$$

*Proof:*
Let $h = \sum a_k b_k$.
Note that $b_k x -1< \lfloor b_k x\rfloor <b_kx$.
Hence $\left|b_k x-\lfloor b_k x\rfloor\right|<1$ and 
$$\left|\sum a_k\lfloor b_k x\rfloor -hx\right|<\sum |a_k|.$$
Therefore $\sum a_k\lfloor b_k x\rfloor \in\{0,1\}$ would imply 
$$ hx<1+\sum |a_k|.$$
If $h\ne0$ this cannot hold for all $x$.
This shows the first claim.

If $t\notin \mathbb Z$ then $\lfloor-t\rfloor +\lfloor t\rfloor= -1$.
Therefore, if $xb_k\notin \mathbb Z$ for all $k$ (e.g. if $x$ is irrational), then 
$$\tag{1}f(x)+f(-x) =\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\left\lfloor b_k x\right\rfloor+\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\left\lfloor -b_k x\right\rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\cdot(-1)$$
Since the left hand side is $\in\{0,1,2\}$, the second claim follows.
If there are irrational numbers $x_0$ and $x_1$ with $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(x_1)=1$, then letting $x=x_0$ in (1), the left hand side is $\le 1$ and with letting $x=x_1$ it is $\ge1$, thus showing the third claim.
$_\blacksquare$

Comment: It is also easy to see that it is not sufficient, since $a_1=a_2=1$, $b_1=-b_2=1$ fulfils that condition, but for $x=0.5$ we get $\lfloor 0.5\rfloor + \lfloor -0.5\rfloor = 0 + (-1) = -1 \notin \{0,1\}$.